# How to use array value in getElementById?

Tags: php, javascript

I have php array like this :

```
<form name="qwerty">
    <? foreach ($products as $product)?>
    <input type="text" name="price1[]" id="<? $product['id']?>" value="<? $product['price1']?>" onkeyup="copy()"/>

    <input type="text" name="price2[]" id="<? $product['id']?>" value="<? $product['price2']?>" />
    <? end foreach?>
</form>
```

how to use that id value in this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy()
{
  var cc1 = document.getElementById('???????');
  var cc2 = document.getElementById('???????');
  cc2.value = cc1.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Why you don't use getElementsByName because you have to id complex.

Comment: Why your PHP variables doesn't have `$`?

Comment: Using `<?` instead of `<?php` is **bad practice**.

Answer (score 0):

Put the product ID in as an argument to the `copy()` function. It can then get the appropriate IDs with string concatenation.

```
<form name="qwerty">
    <? foreach (products as product)?>
    <input type="text" name="price1[]" id="price1_<? $product['id']?>" value="<? product['price1']?>" onkeyup="copy('<? $product['id']?>')"/>

    <input type="text" name="price2[]" id="price2_<? $product['id']?>" value="<? product['price2']?>" />
    <? end foreach?>
</form>

function copy(pid) {
    var cc1 = document.getElementById('price1_'+pid);
    var cc2 = document.getElementById('price2_'+pid);
    cc2.value = cc1.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid syntax in your PHP code:

1. Your variables doesn't contains `$`.
2. You don't have `echo` to output your variables.
3. Your loop must be close with `endforeach`.

---

Consider you have the following array:

```
<?php
    $products = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'price1' => 1, 'price2' => 2),
        array('id' => 2, 'price1' => 1, 'price2' => 2),
        array('id' => 3, 'price1' => 1, 'price2' => 2)
    );
?>
```

And in your HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <input type="text" name="price1[]" id="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>_F" value="<?php echo $product['price1']; ?>"
        onkeyup="copy('<?php echo $product['id']; ?>')" />
    <input type="text" name="price2[]" id="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>_T" value="<?php echo $product['price2']; ?>" />
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And your function will be:

```
<script>
    function copy(id) {
        document.getElementById(id + '_T').value = document.getElementById(id + '_F').value
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <form name="qwerty">
 <?php foreach ($products as $product){?>
    <input type="text" name="price1[]" id="<? echo $product['id']?>" value="<? echo  $product['price1']?>" onkeyup="copy(this)"/>

   <input type="text" name="price2[]" id="mirror<? echo  $product['id']?>" value="<? echo $product['price2']?>" />
 <?php }?>
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function copy(e)
{
  document.getElementById("mirror"+e.id).value=e.value;
}
</script>
```